# How to do long running process in Django view?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, background-task, long-running-processes

I have a django web application and I have to create model for Machine Learning in a view.

It takes a long time so PythonAnyWhere does not allow it and it kills the process when it reaches 300 seconds. According to that, i want to ask two questions.

1. Without celery, django bg task or something else, my view which contains the long running process does not work in order. But when I use debugger, it works correctly. Probably, some lines of code try to work without waiting for each other without debugger. How can i fix this?
2. PythonAnyWhere does not support celery or other long running task packages. They suggest django-background-tasks but in its documentation, the usage is not explained clearly. So I could not integrate it. How can i integrate django-background-tasks?

Thank you.

Comment: Go to a hosting provider that allows you to use celery. pythonanywhere wasn't designed for this kind of purpose.

Comment: 1. I don't understand what you mean by "when I use debugger". On your local machine? And no, python/django is sequential so no line of code will ever be executed without the previous finished (unless you explicitly use asyncio). 2. The purpose of django-background-tasks is not really to run long-running processes in the background, and if python anywhere doesn't allow process to run longer than 300 seconds, it won't help anyway.

Comment: Probably Django's view is not the correct place to do this. HTTP requests should usually complete quickly and return a response.

Comment: When I check the app on local with debugger, the code runs line by line. But when i run the app and i try to do the same process on web page by pressing button, the code does not work line by line. I cannot find its reason.

Comment: Code in a PythonAnywhere web app can *only* run line-by-line because it's single-threaded. Perhaps you have data that is different between local and PythonAnywhere so the code runs on a different path than you expect. You can add debug output to your view (prints to stderr will appear in your error log) to debug the view.

Comment: I've fixed the first issue. But I still could not integrate the bgtask. I've created the tasks.py and I've created the background function, i call it from view but the background function does not work.

Comment: Are you running the process_tasks management command somewhere?

Comment: I've fixed all of the issues. Thanks.